# how to detect TalkBack is active? using Xamarin Forms -Dependency service

Tags: android, dependency-injection, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, talkback

[image]I will like to return true or false if TalkBack is active.

public bool IsVoiceOver()
        {

```
     AccessibilityManager am = (AccessibilityManager) 
     Context.AccessibilityService;

        var a =  am.IsEnabled;
        if (!a) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" DROID voice over   is : " + a);
            return false;
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DROID voice over  is : " + a);
        return true;
        }
    }
```

However, "AccessibilityManager" is not working. I guess is a syntax issue not sure.

Comment: i have made changes in my answer take a look it should work now

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is check with the AccessibilityManager if this is available or not

Something like below:

```
 AccessibilityManager am = (AccessibilityManager)GetSystemService(Context.AccessibilityService);

 if (am.IsEnabled) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" DROID voice over is active);
        return am.IsEnabled;
    }
    else 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DROID voice over is inactive);
        return am.IsEnabled;
    }
```

do not forget to add the following using statements:

```
using Android.Views.Accessibility;
using Android.Content;
```

### UPDATE

To access the GetSystemService method you will need the [Current Activity Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin)

- Install the NuGet package for it.
- Simply call the Init method on OnCreate of your MainActivity `CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle);`
- Then you can call the GetSystemService Method as shown below:

  ```
    AccessibilityManager am = (AccessibilityManager)CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.GetSystemService(Context.AccessibilityService);
  ```

Comment: Please see the screenshot on my original code. got an issue on GETSYSTEMSERVICE is this part of the os or is just a name of any other method? and the usings are included already. Thank you

Comment: You need activity reference for this you need to use it with current activity eg `Activity.GetSystemService()`

Comment: You .got it !! Thank you so much

Comment: @Pxaml if this answers your question kindly mark it as correct

Comment: G. hakim can you please take a look of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55521746/how-to-find-if-user-has-enrolled-any-fingerprints?noredirect=1#comment97748133_55521746