# How to find if user has enrolled any fingerprints

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, fingerprint

I need to identify if the user has any fingerprint register on their device. However, I got an error using this line

```
  FingerprintManagerCompat  fpm = (FingerprintManagerCompat)CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.GetSystemService(Context.FingerprintService);
```

``` error ``

```
{System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
  at app.Droid.lyA.FingerPrint.HasEnrolledFingerprints () [0x00002] in /../../../appmobile/../Droid/lyA/FingerPrint.cs:19 }
```

This is what I need to return.

[image: here is the cast]

Comment: What error are you getting? Please share the error log

Comment: Please check my edit

Comment: It seems that there is an error with the casting you did at `FingerprintManagerCompat  fpm = (FingerprintManagerCompat)CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.GetSystemService(Context.FingerprintService);`
Can you see what `CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.GetSystemService(Context.FingerprintService)` is actually returning. It seems that whatever is being returned here cannot be cast to `FingerprintManagerCompat`

Comment: The cast looks ok to me, I attached an screenshot

Comment: Check my answer. I still believe it's a problem with the cast as that's what the logs are saying. You can try debugging by printing the object returned by your function call before actually casting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer-

It seems that there is an error with the casting you did at

```
FingerprintManagerCompat fpm = (FingerprintManagerCompat)CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.GetSystemService(Context.FingerprintService);
```

It seems that whatever is being returned here cannot be cast to `FingerprintManagerCompat`.

As mentioned in another answer, the correct way to use FingerprintManagerCompat is actually -

```
FingerprintManagerCompat fpm= FingerprintManagerCompat.From(this);
```

I would suggest changing to this and checking if it solves the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Pxaml Please consider leaving an upvote and accepting the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of using FingerprintManagerCompat is actually something like this:

```
FingerprintManagerCompat fpm= FingerprintManagerCompat.From(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity);
```

Good luck!

Revert in case of queries.

Comment: You are a saint! Thanks

Comment: Girl - lol! can you please take a look to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55540809/biometrics-fingerprintmanager-xamarin-forms-on-android-pie-9

Comment: Oh lol sorry, You can use the [BioMetric](https://source.android.com/security/biometric) API's for this