# Biometrics - FingerprintManager Xamarin forms on Android PIE - 9

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, fingerprint, biometrics, android-9.0-pie

FingerprintManager#isHardwareDetected() and FingerprintManager#hasEnrolledFingerprints(). Both of which are deprecated in Android 28.
What else could I use in order to see if fingerprints are enrolled in this version? 
I saw this as an option.

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager =
                    (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
```

if that option is ok, how to translate it into xamarin forms for example ()

```
FingerprintManagerCompat fpm= FingerprintManagerCompat.From(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity);
```

To this :

Comment: Were you able to solve this or do I need to help you out?

Comment: @G.hakim I will swear that I marked your answer as the response, but I don't see it anymore. that helped me with my question.  can you please make the answer available again so I can mark it as the answer. Thanks

Comment: I guess my comment here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55522159/7462031

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Plugin.Fingerprint` to acheved it in android 9.0.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Fingerprint/

There is my GIF of demo(If you first run this project, please make sure you have created fingerprint in you device).
[image]

Because forms just have one activity, If pushed the auth page, we should achieved `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` and `FingerprintDialogFragment`

Here is code of **MainApplication** , it need the `Plugin.CurrentActivity` plugin

```
    [Application]
public class MainApplication : Application, Application.IActivityLifecycleCallbacks
{
    public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer)
      : base(handle, transer)
    {
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        RegisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);

        CrossFingerprint.SetCurrentActivityResolver(() => CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity);

        // uncomment this line to use custom dialog
        //CrossFingerprint.SetDialogFragmentType<MyCustomDialogFragment>();
    }

    public override void OnTerminate()
    {
        base.OnTerminate();
        UnregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    }

    public void OnActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
    }

    public void OnActivityDestroyed(Activity activity)
    {
    }

    public void OnActivityPaused(Activity activity)
    {
    }

    public void OnActivityResumed(Activity activity)
    {
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
    }

    public void OnActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState)
    {
    }

    public void OnActivityStarted(Activity activity)
    {
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
    }

    public void OnActivityStopped(Activity activity)
    {
    }
}
```

Here is code of **MyCustomDialogFragment**

```
   public class MyCustomDialogFragment : FingerprintDialogFragment
{
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your fragment here
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        view.Background = new ColorDrawable(Color.Blue);
        return view;
    }
}
```

There is my code of my demo.

https://github.com/851265601/FrigerPrintDemo

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please try to mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help. you are correct your solution is very valid. However, I was looking more on how to change the new deprecated functions to detect if any fingerprint is available or register on android 9.